# Using $.grep how to filter an array using another array as a filter source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm attempting to apply a filter to a JSON array using another array as my filter source. What would be the most efficient way to do that?

This is my code: my goal is to extract all elements of employees array where employee ids are the same as in employeeFilter array. Similar to SQL, where employeeId in (1,2).

```
var employees = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "john"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "paul"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "mary"
}];

var employeeFilter = [1, 2];

emps = $.grep(employees, function (value, i) {
    for (j = 0; j < employeeFilter.length; j++) {
        return (value.id == employeeFilter[j]); // not working
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient would probably be to not use jQuery at all, but something like `Array.filter`

```
var employees = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "john"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "paul"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "mary"
}];

var employeeFilter = [1, 2];

var emps = employees.filter(function(employee) {
    return employeeFilter.indexOf(employee.id) != -1;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4o0LzxLr/)

Comment: be aware that Array.filter is not supported at least in Internet Explorer 8 and below (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility), but the good news is that you can workaround this using the polyfill present in the MDN page.

Comment: The same goes for `Array.indexOf`. If support for IE8 is needed, one would have to polyfill, however we should stop supporting that old crap.

Comment: I totally agree with you ! And this is why I upvoted your answer. That was only a "just in case" notice :)

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are always returning in first iteration of your employeeFilter, without ever matching to other values in the employeeFilter. A minor change, and it will work as required:

```
var employees = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "john"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "paul"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "mary"
}];

var employeeFilter = [1, 2];

emps = $.grep(employees, function (value) {
    var result = false;
    for (j = 0; j < employeeFilter.length; j++) {
        result = (value.id == employeeFilter[j]); 
        if(result)
            break;
    }
    return result;
});
```

**demo**:http://jsfiddle.net/ugze6dew/